# when I click on Browse &;80(http) i got this screen

Tags: asp.net, mysql, iis

[image]

when I clicked on Browse *;80(http) I got this screen in IIS..what could wrong? please give me solution.

Comment: Look into the error log.

Comment: Show your web.config file content.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the ASP.Net Frameworks.

Also check whether you have configured web config file in a proper manner.

All frameworks are very important as far as the configuration goes.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are running into is a common problem for developers since they start developing on their Desktop or their Documents folder without realizing that only they have access to them. In other words those folders only have ACL's for you. This works ok when you use Visual Studio since they run the process as your identity which makes it all work, however when you use a real server, such as IIS that runs as a service it will no longer run the process as your identity but some service account which will NOT have access to your directory.

You will need to add ACLs for IIS to be able to read the files (IIS_IUSRS or the AppPool Identity like IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool, depending on the settings of your apppool), or move it to a folder that has enough access such as \inetpub\wwwroot\